# bash: .bashrc: line 148: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bashrc

I had to set path in `.bashrc`. I opened it using `vi .bashrc` and by mistake omitted the last line (containing something with `fi`) and then added path. I saved it using `:wq`. While doing `source .bashrc` it is showing:

```
bash: .bashrc: line 148: syntax error: unexpected end of file.
```

These are the last lines of `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
PATH=$PATH:/home/rbh/PROGRAMS.330/bin 
export PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.bashrc` should look something like this

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

PATH=$PATH:/home/rbh/PROGRAMS.330/bin export PATH
```

You deleted last `fi` which was closing the if block condition